# How requesting data from an API

Tags: api, go

I am trying to fetch data from:
[Graduates Data](https://data.gov.sg/dataset/graduates-from-university-first-degree-courses-by-type-of-course?view_id=fa0e401c-6251-4a15-aebc-a5f3d2c85752&resource_id=eb8b932c-503c-41e7-b513-114cffbe2338)

But don't know how to capture data and use it from api and have error if my responseObject isnt defined.

My Code

```
type Response struct {
    Hasil string `json:"result"`
}
type Hasil struct {
    Data []Data `json:"records"`
}
type Data struct {
    Jurusan string `json:"type_of_course"`
    Tahun string `json:"year"`
}
func main () {
    response, err := http.Get("https://data.gov.sg/api/action/datastore_search?resource_id=eb8b932c-503c-41e7-b513-114cffbe2338")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Print(err.Error())
    }
    responseData, err := ioutil.ReadAll(response.Body)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    var responseObject Response
    json.Unmarshal(responseData, &responseObject)
    for i := 0; i < len(responseObject.Hasil.Data); i++ {
        fmt.Println(responseObject.Hasil.Data[i].Jurusan)
    }
}
```

And might best if you can share some reference where i can learn go language from scratch? i have no base on Go Lang

Comment: For language basics take the [tour](https://tour.golang.org/welcome/1), for some idioms you can read [this](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go), and the language [spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec) is very thorough and has answers to the majority of Go-related questions on SO. The [standard library](https://pkg.go.dev/std) is very well documented and also answers a large portion of the questions here. Also take a look at the [faq](https://golang.org/doc/faq).

Comment: Don't ignore the error returned from json.Unmarshal. If an error occurs, don't just log it and carry on as if nothing happened. If http.Get returns an error the response will be nil and you must not use it.

Comment: After you unmarshal the response, it can be still something like nil, so trying to access nested fields isn't really safe, unless you have checked that's the parent isn't nil.